# Recursive JDBC queries are throwing java.lang.StackOverflowError at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.getNBytes(T4CMAREngine.java:1525)

Tags: java, oracle, recursion, jdbc

I am running a program that walks through the hierarchy of deep level structures. It is the data related to a mechanical assembly where one component reports to other that reports to some other.. It has many such levels.

In the recursive method, I get the DB connection from pool and execute the query to get corresponding data and close the connection. Then it goes to the next level in the recursive method. Program runs for multiple of hours as there is huge data to process.

At some point it is throwing the following error. After this error, if I restart the program, it quickly fails with the same error. It is not related to data as the error is thrown at different places each time.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.getNBytes(T4CMAREngine.java:1525)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalNBytes(T4CMAREngine.java:1495)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalBuffer(T4CMAREngine.java:2009)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalCLR(T4CMAREngine.java:1796)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalCLR(T4CMAREngine.java:1930)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalDALC(T4CMAREngine.java:2352)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIuds.unmarshal(T4C8TTIuds.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.receiveCommon(T4CTTIdcb.java:155)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.receive(T4CTTIdcb.java:115)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:705)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:804)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1049)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1154)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1313)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:420)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
    at com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:502)
```

Code is something like this. This method is recursively called till it reaches the end.

```
public static void recursiveWalk(String parent){
         Connection conn = conPool.getConnection();
                  ......                       
              String queryStr= "SELECT childkey from Hierarchy where parentkey='"+parent+"'";                    

               stmt =  conn.createStatement();
             rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(queryStr);

              ...........
                  ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
              while(rs1.next()){   
                 aList.add(rs1.getString("childkey"));

              } 
              rs1.close();
              stmt.close();
              conn.close();  
              for(aList){
              recursiveWalk(tempchild[1],schema,queryTail,topparent,addedchild,  poolconn,level+1);
              }
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your code. :)

Comment: Edvin, I have added the snippet of the code.

Comment: Its *your* code that causes the problem, not the JDBC driver. The reason it always fails in the driver is only that your code calls into the driver from the most recent recursion level. But the bulk of stackframes comes from the call site repeated many times in the exception stack: com.hierarchy.HierarchyWalker.recursiveWalk(HierarchyWalker.java:420)

Comment: Is there a reason you'd doing lots of queries like this, rather than doing the recursion on the database side (hierarchical query, recursive CTE) via a single query execution? You aren't even using a parameterised statement. No wonder it takes a long time to run...

Comment: Durandal, that again is the jdbc statement query "rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(stmtQuery1);" This is the line, the error is thrown.

Comment: Alex, recursion on the database is taking lot of time and query is failing as the recursion could go around 5000 levels at times. So, to avoid the load on the oracle side, I split it into Java recursion + individual DB query for each level.

Comment: @user6460412 - you are still putting a load on the DB, just a different one; and adding a Java load that it seems is too much too - you're basically running out of memory. It would probably be better to get it working in the DB, and you could ask a question about that, showing what you tried and what error is got. And what version of Oracle you're using, as that affects what methods are available.

Comment: Alex, I tried the preparedstatement with parameter option too. Still got the same error. It is just a version I posted that has createstatement.